# How Remove retweet from collected dataset

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, data-mining, tweepy

i have a collected dataset of tweets in python (jupyter notebook). but there are many duplicate tweets. how can i remove these programmaticaly with python (jupyter notebook)

```
csvFile = open('ua.csv', 'a')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
```

```
search_words = "corona"
date_since = "2020-10-13"
```

```
new_search = search_words + " -filter:retweets"
new_search
```

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=search_words,count=100,
                           lang="id",
                           since=date_since).items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of you csv file?

Answer (score 0):

While you're iterating through the list of tweets, you could keep a list of tweets in a set, and check if you've already written that tweet.

```
tweet_set = set() # store tweet ids you've already seen before
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=search_words,count=100,
                           lang="id",
                           since=date_since).items():

    if tweet.id not in tweet_set:
        print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
        csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])

        tweet_set.add(tweet.id) # update the set of tweets
```